# Are there any implementations of Subjective Logic based trust metrics out there?

Tags: java, c, algorithm, logic, probability

[Subjective Logic](http://folk.uio.no/josang/sl/index.html) is fundamental as part of my next project, and I was just wondering if there are any implementations already out there. I've read [**some things**](http://folk.uio.no/josang/sl/Op.html) (not a lot) about the operators but I'm still unsure as to how it is implemented.

Preferably I would like a C/Java/Go/Python implementation

Comment: [Stop reading alot, he might not like it](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.fr/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [demo](http://folk.uio.no/josang/sl/Op.html) page contains a Java applet which can be used to visualise networks of trust using subjective logic. While no source can be obtained for the applet up front, the applet [JAR file](http://folk.uio.no/josang/sl/SLWebDemo.jar) can be decompiled using a program such as [JD](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) (java decompiler) and from there reverse engineered.

The code somewhat provides a library and is the **only** example of subjective logic in code I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see any example codes for subjective logic after a google search. This concept is more into AI and logic based languages like Prolog will have to be employed. Also if you have a rule evaluation engine (like CLIPS rule-engine as mentioned [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.187.3108&rep=rep1&type=pdf)), then good to go.

There are couple of [algorithms proposed](http://folk.uio.no/josang/papers/JHP2006-ACSC.pdf) which leverage subjective logic and can be coded in java or C right away.